# Cant Generate pie chart using chartjs from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, canvasjs

I can't generate `pie chart` using `canvas.JS`. I already iterate them through loop.
JSON itself return value like below

```
[[{"label":"belum","x":1},{"label":"sudah","x":5}]]
```

I am using below code to get JSON data.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            
            var abc = [];
            
            $.getJSON("json/data_wilayah1.php", function (result) {
                
                for( var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    abc.push({ label: result[i].label, y: result[i].y });
                }
                
                var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                    animationEnabled: true,
                    title:{
                        text: "Ketersediaan Perangkat Jasa Akses Internet Redesain USO"
                    },    
                    toolTip:{
                    shared: true,
                    },
                    data: [
                        {
                            type:"pie",
                            name: "{label}",
                            legendText: "{label}",
                            showInLegend: true, 
                            toolTipContent: "{label}: <strong>{x}%</strong>",
                            indexLabel: "{label} - {x}%",
                            dataPoints: abc
                        }
                    ]
                });
                chart.render();
                
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a typo in looping.

```
abc.push({ label: result[i].label, y: result[i].y });
```

Do you have Y property in your response ?

In your Json response it's X so this result[i].y will return undefined.

I think you're supplying undefined value to co-ordinate.

[This is the one which is not working](https://jsfiddle.net/VIvekJain202/0j7fvcgz/1/)

[This is a working one (Updated)](https://jsfiddle.net/VIvekJain202/k1xh8a5q/)

Comment: Thx for your feedback!
already change x to y in JSON file.
Now it does appear but only title.
Pie chart isnt showing yet

Comment: well Y axis is not exceeding 100, I use the same JSON as above. I do wonder why theres "undefined - %" near the title?

Comment: it appear to be tooltip. legend also showing undefined

Comment: Here's a working one https://jsfiddle.net/VIvekJain202/k1xh8a5q/ you can check. @JoyVincentius

Comment: does my JSON file already in right format?  
[[{"label":"belum","x":1},{"label":"sudah","x":5}]]
cause I see datapoint always refer [{},{},..]

Comment: Just check the updated link i built a chart with data of your JSON i think you can easily spot the misses.

Comment: Found a way!    using dataPoints: result[0]   how does it possible?

Comment: Check you JSON properly you will know.you're getting it like this [[xyx]]